# summing over a matrix in different parts of that matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In a matrix, how can we sum part by part of the elements? Consider the primary matrix in a way that can be divided into smaller m by n matrix. then i want to sum the whole elements of each m by n matrix together and put the number instead of the m by n matrix
for example consider the following matrix, i want to sum every four elements and create another matrix:

```
A = [1  2  3  4
     5  6  7  8
     9  10 11 12
     13 14 15 16];
```

And after summing i want to have:

```
B = [14 22
     46 54];
```

I this example i summed 4 elements as a matrix of 2 by 2 then for example the result of summing 1,2,5 and 6 seats in the first element of the new matrix.

Comment: Consider the primary matrix in a way that can be divided into smaller m by n matrix. then i want to sum the whole elements of each m by n matrix together and put the number instead of the m by n matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Let

```
m = 2; %// number of rows per block
n = 2; %// number of columns per block
```

You can do the sum with [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) (from the Image Processing Toolbox), which is very suited for this task:

```
B = blockproc(A, [m n], @(x) sum(x.data(:)));
```

Or, if you build the appropriate indices, you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,2));
B = accumarray([ceil(ii(:)/n) ceil(jj(:)/m)], A(:))
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach -

```
B = squeeze(sum(reshape(sum(reshape(A,m,[])),size(A,1)/m,n,[]),2))
```

Another approach if you would like to avoid `squeeze`, which is sometimes slower -

```
B = reshape(sum(reshape(reshape(sum(reshape(A,m,[])),size(A,1)/m,[])',n,[])),[],size(A,1)/m)'
```